# Using default popups to show Django Forms errors

Tags: django, django-forms

When defining a form using Django Forms, if I have an EmailField, I will get some neat popups like I show in the pictures:

[image: Chrome]
[image: Firefox]

But if I introduce a custom validation, I am unable to show errors to user in the same way (with a popup)

This is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from launcher.models import InterestedUser
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class JoinForm(forms.ModelForm):
# this is the only field that is actually filled by the user
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=128, help_text="Introduce la cuenta de gmail que tienes asociada a tu"
                                                   "dispositivo Android",
                         widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': "w-input email_input",
                                                        'placeholder': 'Tu email de Google'}),
                         required=True, validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(gmail.com)+$',
                                                                   message="La dirección de email no es válida",
                                                                   code="invalid_gmail_address")])
print("atributos {0}".format(email.widget.attrs['class']))

# this other fields will have the same value and go hidden in the form
name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial="(not specified)")
subject = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial="(no subject)")
via = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial="Join")
content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial="no content")

def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

    try:
        beta_tester = InterestedUser.objects.get(email=email)
    # Si el email no existiese entonces salimos del clean_email y devolvemos el valor (aunque no se haya modificado)
    except InterestedUser.DoesNotExist:
        return email
    # Si el email ya existía sacamos un error de Validación:
    raise forms.ValidationError("Ya estabas anotado como Beta Tester, introduce un email diferente!")


class Meta:
    model = InterestedUser
    fields = ('email', 'name', 'subject', 'via', 'content',)
```

And this is how I render it in the template:

```
            <div class="w-form formulario" id="formulario">
                <form class="w-clearfix formulario_subscribe" name="email-form" id="join_form" method="post" data-name="Email Form" action="/">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                        {{  hidden }}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                        {{ field.errors }}
                        {{ field.help_text }}
                        {{ field }}
                    {% endfor %}
                    <input class="w-button email_submit_button" type="submit" id="btn_send" value="Join" data-wait="Un momento!..."/>
                    {% if messages %}
                        <ul class="messages">
                            {% for message in messages %}
                                <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    {% endif %}
                </form>
            </div>
```

I have a RegexValidator and I would like to show the error message if the user input doesn't pass the validator in the same way (popups) that the default validator does it! Any ideas??

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this popup is created by the browser validating the HTML5 email field(looks like chrome) you can disable this validation adding the `novalidate` attribute to the form field. Or more interesting you can use `pattern` to check for gmail.com addresses, something like:

```
<input type="email" pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@gmail.com$" />
```

If you want to validate on the client side you can use something like [parsley](https://github.com/agiliq/Django-parsley)

Also instead of validate emails with a regex you can check [EmailValidator](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/validators.py#L137). There's a property `domain_whitelist` that you can use to restrict gmail.com domains.

Comment: yes, the first picture is Chrome, the second Firefox! I will try tomorrow with the advices you game me and check the answer as correct it it goes well! thanks a lot.

Comment: Perfect. Good luck with chattyhive! ;)

Comment: :O thanks a lot (jaja no me daba cuenta de quién eras!)